# unable to save new xml file using XmlDocument() after using Xpath expression.AddSort(...)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I using C#.NET 2.0 and would like to sort an xml file using XPath and then save it with xmlDoc.Save. But, xml file saved is same original xml without XPath processing. Here is the code:

```
    public static void SortOneLevel()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("abc.xml");

        XPathNavigator navigator = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
        XPathExpression expression = navigator.Compile("Root/Test");
        expression.AddSort("TestPhase", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.None, string.Empty, XmlDataType.Number);

        xmlDoc.Save("abc1.xml"); //check abc1, same as abc, not sorted

        //Check if it is sorted
        XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select(expression);
        foreach (XPathNavigator item in iterator)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(item.Value); //Check printout, sorted
        }

        xmlDoc.Save("abc2.xml"); //check abc2, same as abc, not sorted
}
```

My XML file example is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>

<Test>
<TestPhase>222</TestPhase>
<TestFlow>1</TestFlow>
<TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
</Test>

<Test>
<TestPhase>214</TestPhase>
<TestFlow>1</TestFlow>
<TestParameter>2</TestParameter>
</Test>

<Test>
<TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
<TestFlow>3</TestFlow>
<TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
</Test>

<Test>
<TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
<TestFlow>2</TestFlow>
<TestParameter>2</TestParameter>
</Test>

<Test>
<TestPhase>2</TestPhase>
<TestFlow>1</TestFlow>
<TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
</Test>
.
.
.
.
</Root>
```

The printout for the console.writeline inside foreach loop is :

```
131
122
211
212
221
222
311
.
.
.
.
1011
1012
1021
1022
21412
22211
```

This means that expression has successfully sorted it.  But, may I have your advice how to save it ? 
I am novice to XML. I need your help.  Your effort is very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: XPath is only for xml requests but not for modification.

Comment: Many thanks Alexander Petrov.  what should I do if I want to save this request as new xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

As alluded in the comments, XPath is a query language - you can't use XPath to modify a document.

You could use LINQ to XML to get the `Test` elements, sort them, and then add them to a new document:

```
var original = XDocument.Load("abc1.xml");

var sorted = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root",
        original.Elements("Root")
            .Elements("Test")
            .OrderBy(x => (int) x.Element("TestPhase"))
    )
);

sorted.Save("abc2.xml");
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DMeyY8) for a demo.

Comment: Many thanks Charles Mager.  This is a good solution.  But, I am use on ly .NET 2.0, which do not have linq.  Do you have any idea ? which is the best way to do it ? I guess its only XPath can easily do it.

Comment: @newbuntu apologies, I missed that note in the question. Is there a reason you can't update? Support for .NET 2.0 [ended in 2011](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=.NET%20Framework&Filter=FilterNO), and .NET 3.5 SP1 or .NET 4.5.2 and later both contain LINQ to XML

Comment: okay, sure, thanks Charles Mager.  Although not supported, my requirement is to .NET 2.0. I think I have to use XSLT to 3 level sort my xml file. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("abc.xml");

XPathNavigator navigator = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression expression = navigator.Compile("Root/Test");
expression.AddSort("TestPhase", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.None, string.Empty, XmlDataType.Number);

XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select(expression);


// Delete old (unsorted) nodes.
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.RemoveAll();

var rootNavigator = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator();

// Add sorted nodes to root.
foreach (XPathNavigator item in iterator)
{
    rootNavigator.AppendChild(item);
}

xmlDoc.Save("abc2.xml");
```